# PHP ftp_pwd returns empty

Tags: php, ajax, ftp

I'm writing a php script that gets called via ajax in javascript.  I'm tyring to connect to an ftp server and list all the files in the "public_html" folder.
I also wanted to print the current ftp dir but when when I try, it prints as empty in the console.
 I can connect to the ftp server, but I can't tell what dir is the current one.

```
//Get ftp user/pass
$ftp_server = "ftp." . $_POST['hostname'];
$ftp_username = $_POST['user'];
$ftp_userpass = $_POST['pass'];

echo "console.log('attempting to connect to ftp host: $ftp_server, user:     $ftp_username, password: $ftp_userpass');\n";

$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("alert('Could not connect to $ftp_server');\n");
// turn passive mode on
//ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);
ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, 'public_html');
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);


// then do something...
echo "console.log('Connected to FTP');\n";
// get contents of the current directory
$curdir = ftp_pwd($ftp_conn);
echo "console.log('Current dir: $curdir');\n";
$contents = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, ".");
// output $contents
echo "var files = [];";
foreach ($contents as $file){
    echo "var tempFile = '$file';\n
        files.push(tempFile);\n";
}
echo "console.log(files);\n";
// close connection 
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
?>
```

Comment: `echo "console.log(files);\n";` your code is php not  javascript.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have specified, that the data echoed by the php is then evalutaed in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

swap these two lines from:

```
ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, 'public_html');
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
```

to:

```
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);
ftp_chdir($ftp_conn, 'public_html');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some problems, when using ftp_pasv();

Try to comment this line:

```
ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);
```

Comment: I have commented out that line, but the current dir still outputs as empty

Comment: Have you any errors? (try using error_reporting(E_ALL) or try catch)

Comment: It gives me a warning: Warning:  ftp_pwd(): You aren't logged in in /home/loganmc/public_html/cms/scripts/php/ftp_Connect.php on line 21 which is the local path.

Comment: Place the ftp_login before ftp_chdir